# How to transfer data from one component of AppModule to any component of FeatureModule?

Tags: angular

I want to transfer data from search component to otherModule/otherComponent. Is there any way to achieve this without using services?

```
-AppModule
    -AppComponent
        -searchComponent

-FeatureModule
    -otherComponent
```

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of options to do that but right solution is using service like described here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: And would be great if you provide plunker for your case.

Answer (score 1):

There are serval ways

1. You can put information in url and catch it in you feature component
   using router.
2. You can put information in LocalStorage and read in in your feature module.
3. You can use EventEmmiter to pass data
4. You can use Subject/BehaviorSubject/ReplaySubject to achieve this from rxjs.

I hope this help.

Comment: <app-component>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-component>

=> pageOneComponent appears in <router-outlet>. Is it possible to emit event and catch it at app component?

Comment: Yes you can use BehaviourSubject for that, every time you will pass data to Behaviour Subject you can catch subscribe in app component and cach it.